How to get details of Ad Sets/Campaigns that are having "creative fatigue" and similar errors with Facebook Graph API?
Using cURL, I am trying to get list of AdSets/Ad Campaigns that are having errors like "creative fatigue" with the help of Facebook Graph API.
I checked Graph API documentation, but couldn't find it. I also tried checking out API Explorer tool, but couldn't find a way to get this information.
Even ChatGPT and other AIs couldn't be of help as the references they give do not work now, current version is 20, but AIs give v13, v16 and so on.
Following are a couple of API endpoints from the many I have tried:

https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/<adset_id>?fields=id,name,creative{status}&access_token=<access_token>

https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/act_{ad_account_id}/adsets?fields=name,creative_status


I am expecting an endpoint that will help me fetch all the adsets or adcampaigns which are having the error of "creative fatigue" and other similar errors.
